# Customize django admin dashboard

Tags: django, django-admin

In Django 1.11 it's possible customize the dashboard of admin area (index page)? I need to show some table of data or graph.
I've tried to override index() method ma it doesn't work.

```
class MyAdminSite():
def index(self, request, extra_context=None):
    extra_context = extra_context or {}
    extra_context["test"] = "test"
    return super(MyAdminSite, self).index(request, extra_context)
```

Comment: can you please tell me. What exactly are you looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by defining a templateg with several @register.simple_tag and then calling back into my index template